# Remove Twitter Typeahead from Text Box

Tags: javascript, typeahead, typeahead.js

I am trying to disable all text boxes on my form. One of these boxes has a typeahead on it. When I do:

```
$(#textbox).attr('disabled', true);
```

It is no longer enabled, but the color does not switch like all of the other text boxes do when they become disabled.

I believe this is due to the twitter typeahead and I am wondering if there is a way around it. Does anyone know how to override the text box background color or remove the typeahead completely when the text box is disabled?

I have tried `.unbind()` and `.addClass("greyBackground")` but neither of these seem to do the trick.

Comment: I see the color changing just fine

Comment: @Ian what implementation are you using to disable the text box?

Comment: Is disabled properly here also (background is changed in a clean "fresh" bootstrap) - maybe `$("#textbox").attr(` (using quotes) would help?

Comment: fyi, `.attr()` is the wrong method when setting properties like disabled. use `.prop()` for this (but in this case neither do the job)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you don't care about maintaining the typeahead.js functionality while the `textarea` is disabled, you can destroy the typeahead like so:

```
$('#textbox').typeahead('destroy');
```

This will reset/remove any attributes/styles typeahead.js may have added. If later on you wanted to add back the typeahead.js functionality, you could reinitialize it with:

```
$('#textbox').typeahead({ /* configs */ });
```

Also, typeahead.js doesn't support `textarea` elements out of the box, so unless you're using a forked version, you shouldn't assume typeahead.js will work as expected.

Comment: It should be mentioned that `.typeahead('destroy')` is not available in Bootstrap version 2.2.2.

Comment: Thanks @Eye. I've been searching for awhile any every post says to use destroy but it doesn't work. Now I know why. Anyone know an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap 2.2.2 there is no `.typeahead('destroy')` function, so the following does remove all the listeners it was previously bound to and the DOM element it has created.

```
$('#textbox').off()
        .data('typeahead')
        .$menu
        .off()
        .remove();
```

Comment: I'm still on Bootstrap 2.3.2 and I found that if I wanted to re-add the typeahead later, I also had to remove the typeahead object using `.data('typeahead', null)`